# Не могу решить задачу

Tags: алгоритм, олимпиада

Не могу решить задачу второй день. Наверное я неправильно понял условие.

Забавная игра

Вы с друзьями играете в следующую игру. Друзья пишут на доске подряд N натуральных чисел. Ваша задача — найти как можно больше подряд идущих чисел, которые бы делились на одно и то же число, большее 1. Так как вручную искать ответ сложно, вы решили написать программу, которая сделает работу за вас.

Входные данные

В первой строке входных данных задано число N(1 ≤ N ≤ 100000). Во второй строке записано через пробел N целых чисел A1...AN(1 ≤ Ai ≤ 1000, 1 ≤ i ≤ N). Это те самые числа, которые написали ваши друзья. Они даны в том же порядке, в котором они расположены на доске.

Выходные данные

Ваша программа должна вывести одно целое число — наибольшее количество подряд идущих чисел заданной последовательности, которые бы делились на одно и то же натуральное число, большее 1.

Примеры

Ввод

```
3
6 10 15
```

Вывод

```
2
```

Пытался так, но получаю WL

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n,ans=0;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n+1];
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)cin>>a[i];
    a[n]=1;
    for(int i = 1;i<n;i++){
        int g=__gcd(a[i],a[i-1]); 
        if(g>1)ans++;
        while(g>1 && i<n){
            ans++;
            i++;
            g=__gcd(g,a[i]); 
        }
    }
    if(ans)cout<<ans; 
    else cout<<1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `[2, 2, 1, 2, 2]` выдаст ответ `4`?

Comment: a[n]=1. Вроде бы выйти за границу не должно. На  2 2 1 2 2 наверное 4, но сам точно не знаю

Comment: Прочитайте условие ещё раз и поймите какой должен быть ответ.

Comment: Вроде бы 4 , но на 100% не уверен(

Comment: да, это не так будет 2. Простите меня я новичок в программировании просто(

Comment: Дайте ссылку на проверяющую систему, пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [помогите решить задачу на питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138603/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к ai небольшое(меньше 1000), то можно перебирать этот самый делитель в цикле от 2 до 1000, а вторым циклом проходить по массиву и искать наибольшую последовательность.

Comment: я не уверен, что нужно искать наибольшую последовательность

Comment: Все с тобой понятно

Comment: Спасибо вам. Вы были правы. По условию я не понял, что нужно искать наибольшую последовательность

Comment: да прав, исправил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Если некоторый комплект чисел имеет общий делитель больший единицы, то эти же числа имеют общий простой делитель.

Заведём словарь: ключи простые числа, значения индексы. Перебираем числа ***a<sub>k</sub>*** с доски. На итерации ***k*** словарь содержит пару ***p<sub>i</sub>***, ***j<sub>i</sub>*** если все числа в интервале ***[j<sub>i</sub>, k]*** делятся на ***p<sub>i</sub>***.
На итерации ***k*** из словаря удаляются все записи которые не делят ***a<sub>k</sub>***. Все новые простые делители ***a<sub>k</sub>*** добавляются в словарь со значениями ***k***. Когда запись из словаря удаляется, обновляется максимум длины последовательности.

Сколько может быть различных элементов в словаре одновременно? Ключи словаря - простые числа, на которые делится число ***a<sub>k</sub>*** - другие мы вычеркнули. ***a<sub>k</sub> ≤ 1000***. ***2 · 3 · 5 · 7 · 11 = 2310 > 1000***. Следовательно, словаре не более четырёх элементов.

Как быстро разложить ***a<sub>k</sub>*** на простые? Проверить делимость на все простые меньшие ***32*** (***√1000***). Их ***11*** штук.

```
import math


def prime_divisors(n):
    assert n <= 1000

    for p in (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31):
        if p * p > n:
            break
        if n % p == 0:
            yield p
            while n % p == 0:
                n //= p
    if n > 1:
        yield n


def lengths():
    n = int(input())
    divs = {}
    for i, a in enumerate(map(int, input().split())):
        new_divs = set(prime_divisors(a))
        old_divs = set(divs)
        for d in old_divs - new_divs:
            yield i - divs[d]
            del divs[d]
        for d in new_divs - old_divs:
            divs[d] = i
    for i in divs.values():
        yield n - i

        
print(max(lengths(), default=0))
```

> ```
> $ time echo -e "3\n6 10 15" | python divisible-in-a-row.py 
> 2
>
> real  0m0.027s
> user  0m0.024s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

Сто тысяч случайных чисел за четверть секунды:

> ```
> $ wc -w temp.txt
> 100001 temp.txt
>
> $ time python divisible-in-a-row.py < temp.txt
> 16
>
> real  0m0.230s
> user  0m0.228s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```