# Оптимизация алгоритма "Забавная игра"

Tags: c++, циклы, оптимизация, теория-чисел

Помогите, пожалуйста, оптимизировать алгоритм по времени выполнения. Признаюсь, переписал его с питона, потому что мой выполнялся ещё дольше. Мне кажется нужно концептуально поменять решение.
Вот задание:

Забавная игра

Вы с друзьями играете в следующую игру. Друзья пишут на доске подряд N натуральных чисел. Ваша задача — найти как можно больше подряд идущих чисел, которые бы делились на одно и то же число, большее 1. Так как вручную искать ответ сложно, вы решили написать программу, которая сделает работу за вас.

Входные данные

В первой строке входных данных задано число N(1 ≤ N ≤ 100000). Во второй строке записано через пробел N целых чисел A1...AN(1 ≤ Ai ≤ 1000, 1 ≤ i ≤ N). Это те самые числа, которые написали ваши друзья. Они даны в том же порядке, в котором они расположены на доске.

Выходные данные

Ваша программа должна вывести одно целое число — наибольшее количество подряд идущих чисел заданной последовательности, которые бы делились на одно и то же натуральное число, большее 1.

Пример:
Ввод
3
6 10 15
Вывод
2

Моя программа:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <deque>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

using lli = long long;
using lld = long double;
using ulli = unsigned long long;
using usi = unsigned short;

template <typename T2>
T2 gcd(T2 a, T2 b)
{
    if (a < b) swap(a, b);
    if (b == 0) return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}

int main() {
    lli n, mx = 0, cur_g;
    cin >> n;
    vector <lli> a;
    lli x;
    for (lli i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> x;
        a.push_back(x);
    }

    for (lli i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cur_g = a[i];
        if (n - i < mx) break;
        lli p = 0;
        for (lli j = i; j < n; j++) {
            cur_g = gcd(cur_g, a[j]);
            if (cur_g == 1) break;
            ++p;
            if (mx < p) mx = p;
        }
    }
    cout << mx;
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%94%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8C%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%83%D1%82+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4+N+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85+%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу решить задачу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1303853/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%83)

Comment: Я оттуда и взял решение, оно не проходит по времени

Comment: Вы не то решение взяли.

Comment: В последнем комментарии слишком сложный для меня пока что питон, я хотел бы на плюсах увидеть решение.

Comment: Прочитайте описание решения и напишите своё. Там всё просто.

Comment: точнее понять в чём у меня ошибка

Comment: Ваша ошибка в том что ваш алгоритм квадратичный. Быстрый алгоритм - линейный.

Comment: Напишите алгоритм который решает задачу для "последовательности чётных чисел", для "последовательности чисел делящихся на 3" и т.п. Это алгоритм надо вызвать одиннадцать раз. Времени на C++ хватит.

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, простое по мере чтения построение массива делимости на 11 простых чисел, укладывающихся в делители 1000.
После чего 11 проходов по этим массивам. O(N), несмотря на 12 в сумме проходов :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int p[11] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31 };

int v[11][100000] = {};

int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        int M;
        cin >> M;
        for(int j = 0; j < 11; ++j)
            if (M%p[j] == 0) v[j][i] = 1;
    }
    int M = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 11; ++j)
    {
        int K = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            if (v[j][i] == 0)
            {
                if (M < K) { M = K; }
                K = 0;
            }
            else ++K;
        if (M < K) M = K;
    }

    cout << M;

}
```

благополучно проходит https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view.php?id=7847

Comment: Спасибо огромное, на питон не надо переводить, мне плюсы нужны. Попробую еще немного сам решить по-другому, но если что ваш способ использую.

Comment: Ой, какое счастье! а то я уже полез изучать, как работать с массивами в python... :)

Comment: А можно спросить, зачем вы вынесли массивы в глобальную видимость? Насколько я слышал это не очень красивый тон. Без наезда, просто интересно)

Comment: Да чтоб в стек такой объем не засовывать. 11 раз по 100000 да еще по 4 байта — итого 4 с половиной мегабайта. Может и не влезть, я не знаю, какой там у них стек по умолчанию, в GCC...